# Focus uibutton inside uicollectionviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I have a custom `UICollectionView Cell`. The layout of the cell looks like this

```
 - ContentView
    - UILabel
    - UIView --> buttonView
          - UIButton
```

`ButtonViews` hidden property is standard set to true. 
When the user taps the cell. `ButtonView` becomes visible.

What my problem now is, is that I don't get the focus to the `uibutton` inside the `buttonView`

This are pieces of my code:

In my viewController:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ShoppingCartCell

        cell.buttonView.hidden = false
        cell.buttonView.updateFocusIfNeeded()

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
    }
```

In my custom cell:

```
   public override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if (self.focused)
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
        }
        else
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
           buttonView.hidden = true
        }


        super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

        guard let nextFocusedView = context.nextFocusedView else { return }

        switch nextFocusedView {
        case self.buttonView:
            self.focusGuide.preferredFocusedView = self.deleteButton
        default:
            self.focusGuide.preferredFocusedView = nil
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it a custom UIButton? If so, you need to handle the focus appearance yourself.

Comment: No it's a standard UIButton

Comment: @Steaphann try my answer .

Answer (score 1):

You hide buttonview for particular condition but you not show again for another condition.  Try this code,

```
public override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if (self.focused)
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
            buttonView.hidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
           buttonView.hidden = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things I subclassed UIButton for your button you use in a cell, and noticed that calling

```
self.focusGuide.preferredFocusedView = cell.aButton
```

that is not making the button in focus, self.focused on that button is false as well as didUpdateFocusInContext in that button class is not getting called.

As a temporary fix and/or future exploration/experimenting you can "fake" focus on your button. For that, as I mentioned before, subclass from UIButton and make your own button class.

In that class add something like this:

```
func makeFocused()
{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations:
            {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
            },
            completion:
            {
                finished in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations:
                    {
                        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    },
                    completion: nil)
        })

        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
}
```

Similarly add unfocus method. Then call focus/unfocus on your button inside of the:

```
class YourCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var aButton: CustomButton!

private var focusGuide = UIFocusGuide()

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
{
    super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

    guard let nextFocusedView = context.nextFocusedView else { return }
    guard let prevFocusedView = context.previouslyFocusedView else { return }

    if let cell = nextFocusedView as? YourCustomCell
    {
        cell.aButton.makeFocused()
        self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
        return
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)